# Script that changes content of a div throught a select doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

The purpose of my code is to make visible a div that has the same id that the select option I've chosen. But there is more stuff. The div to make visible has an iframe that has to be resized fitting the content. Each iframe contains an Excel sheet (in htm extension). I paste all of my code, including resizing function. That works perfectly on Chrome and Opera, but it doesn't run well on IE and FF.

The problem appears when i select a new div. In Chrome and Opera i see the new iframe properly resized when i change the select option, but in IE and FF i can't see anything. I've checked that the display propierty of the div i've selected is set to block, cause it may be a problem of jQuery or Resize function.

I spent a lot of time trying to fix it, but i still find the solution.

There is my code:

CSS:

```
#sheetsContainer div{display: none;}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="sheets">
    <option value="sheet1">Sheet 1</option>
    <option value="sheet2">Sheet 2</option>
</select>


<div id="sheetsContainer">
    <div id="sheet1">
        <iframe frameborder="0" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' src="indicadors/2014/1_3_4.htm"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="sheet2">
        <iframe frameborder="0" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' src="indicadors/2014/1_3_4_183.htm"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
    function resizeIframe(obj) {
        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
        obj.style.width = "100%";
    }

    $("#sheets").change(function(){
        $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
    });

    $("#sheets").change();
```

This is a test, since my real purpose is to use bootstrap's tab panel instead of the dropdown select. I wanted to minimize the problem to make it more intelligible to you. In fact, with Chrome and Opera bootstrap's tabs also work, but it doesn't with IE and FF.

Thanks all for your help!

**EDIT:**

With FF and IE I can see only the first div of the selector. When I switch to another div I can't see anything, but if i switch again to first div I can see it propely. In my code, i can see 'sheet1' but I can't see 'sheet2'. If i refresh the page with 'sheet2' selected, now i can see sheet2, but if I switch to sheet1 i can't see nothing.

You can see what i have at https://gpaq.upc.edu//lldades/2014/indicador.asp?index=1_3_4 . Compare it with Chrome and FF to see the problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox, you need to give it a bit of time to load the iframe. Here is the recommendation:

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    setInterval(function(){resizeIframeNow(obj);},3000); // wait around 3 seconds
}

function resizeIframeNow(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    obj.style.width = "100%";
}
```

I would prefer removing the + 'px' after scrollHeight.

As for IE, I would recommend calling the resize function from the HTML content of the iframe by using the **window.frameElement** (iframe parent) object towards the end of the HTML in your case maybe 1_3_4_183.html:

```
....
<script>

var h = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollHeight + 30; // add 30 to prevent scrollbar from appearing
window.frameElement.height=h;

</script>

</body>
```

But for IE to work, you still need to change the iframe settings a bit:

from

```
<iframe frameborder="0" onload="javascript:resizeIframe(this);" src="./Llibre de dades_files/1_3_4.html" style="height: 7718px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

to

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" onload="javascript:resizeIframe(this);" src="./Llibre de dades_files/1_3_4.html" height="7718" width="100%"></iframe>
```

If you define the style for IE, the size will be stuck at that size and will ignore any script trying to change it.

You also need to tell resizeIframe() to bypass if the browser is IE:

```
var ie = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1);

function resizeIframe(obj) {
    if (!ie) {
        setInterval(function(){resizeIframeNow(obj);},3000); // wait around 3 seconds
    }
}

function resizeIframeNow(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    obj.style.width = "100%";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! I only needed the f***cking delay. If I add the delay, it works for every browser, included IE, no needed to add frameElement code on all of my files (cause there are about 100 files xD). Really thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

While assignment of width in IE and FF, i think you should consider assigning it in pixels.For example, if 100% of window is 1280 px, then assign width as 1280px instead of 100%. I am not sure whether this is the apt solution for you but it did work for me once.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem of iframe's width. In fact, i try your solution and it doesn't do anything. But thanks for the answer aswell :-)

Comment: @Katalhama sorry that it does not work. I wil try and get back if I find anything.

Comment: I edited the post with a new explanation. Hope it will be helpfull for you all ;)